# Filtering dataframe in spark and saving as avro

Tags: xml, parsing, apache-spark, rdd, avro

I am trying to save a dataframe as avro file. I have read in an xml file that has many nested layers. It stores it as a dataframe. The dataframe is stored successfully. The XML has many namespace headers such as @nso, @ns1, @ns2 etc. These become the headers in the dataframe.

When I try to save it as avro file it gives me this error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: Illegal initial character: @ns0

Code:

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
         .setMaster("local[2]")
         .setAppName("conversion")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

val df = sqlContext.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
  .option("rowTag", "Stuff")
  .load("sample.xml")

df.printSchema()
df.show()

df.write
  .format("com.databricks.spark.avro")
  .save("output")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A valid Avro name [has to start with a letter or an underscore](https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/da22ffcba82efa50aa384b3acdf26561085e14f6/lang/java/avro/src/main/java/org/apache/avro/Schema.java#L1146) so you have either rename columns generated from attributes or specify alternative prefix. `spark-csv` allows you to configure attribute prefix using `attributePrefix` property:

```scala
val df = sqlContext.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
  .option("rowTag", "Stuff")
  .option("attributePrefix", "attr_")  // or some other prefix of your choice
  .load("sample.xml")
```

Comment: I tried this solution. It replaces the xmlns headers of xml - the ones with @ symbol successfully. However, when the ns0, ns1 elements in the nested layers inside is still having issues. Do you know how to replace those?

Comment: Could you gist a small example input on which it fails? It sounds like a bug.

Comment: OK, so remaining problem is that `ns1:PublicID` is not a valid name either, due to `:`? If so I don't think there is another solution than renaming and this is not exactly straightforward with nested objects.

Comment: I've been thinking about how to solve this. Do you think converting to rdd and filtering all the : out using regex would make sense?

Comment: There is no need to touch data. All what is needed is rewriting schema. It is not particularly complex object and can be easily traversed with renaming if needed.